# Lithium Proton Fission

Tags: thermodynamics, nuclear-physics, protons, isotopes

What will happen if I fire a proton beam at a Lithium-6 nucleus? What products will it produce? Is it exothermic and if so, how much energy is released? How would you calculate it?

Comment: Well, fission is very unlikely to occur with such small masses

Comment: @Orion73 - and yet, when you hit $^{7}$Li with a proton you get 2 $\alpha$ particles...

Answer (score 3):

As with many nuclear physics questions, a good first place to look is your local Evaluated Nuclear Structure Data File source (I generally use the mirror at [Brookhaven](https://www.nndc.bnl.gov/ensdf/).

Adding a proton to Lithium-6 makes a compound nucleus with mass 7, so enter 7 in the search box and hit Search. Look down the list until you get to $^{7}$Be. There you will see an entry for "6LI(P,P),(P,2P),(P,PA)" - those are the reactions that have been found and used for mapping the $^{7}$Be energy levels.

Another good resource is the Nuclear Data Evaluation Project at the [Triangle Universities Nuclear Laboratory](http://www.tunl.duke.edu/nucldata/index.shtml). There you can search by mass, and in particular pay attention to the Energy Isobar diagrams. There you will see that $^{6}$Li+p comes in some 5.6MeV above the $^{7}$Be ground state, and not near any excited nuclear states.

So, you have a variety of reactions that are possible.

Answer (score 0):

Wikipedia gives the following sequence of reactions for [lithium burning](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lithium_burning), but unfortunately it does not mention how much energy it produces. This sequence is often classed as a fusion reaction, although the last step does involve fission. Many writers prefer to just call it lithium burning.

$$\begin{align}\\
\mathrm p+{}^6_3\mathrm{Li}&\longrightarrow{}^7_4\mathrm{Be}\ \text{(unstable)}\\
^7_4\mathrm{Be}+\mathrm e^-&\longrightarrow{}^7_3\mathrm{Li}+\nu\\
\mathrm p+{}^7_3\mathrm{Li}&\longrightarrow{}^8_4\mathrm{Be}\ \text{(unstable)}\\
^8_4\mathrm{Be}&\longrightarrow{}2\ ^4_4\mathrm{He}+\ \text{energy}\\
\end{align}$$

These reactions can occur at a lower temperature than the standard [proton-proton chain](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proton-proton_chain_reaction), which is the dominant family of fusion reaction in stars less than 1.3 solar masses. (The [CNO cycle](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/CNO_cycle) is more important in larger stars).

Lithium burning is important in [T Tauri](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/T_Tauri_star) pre-main sequence stars.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the reactions explained in the other answers, there are several other processes that can happen:

- **Elastic scattering**, in which the proton scatters off of the whole nucleus at once without producing anything new;
- **Quasielastic scattering**, in which the proton scatters off of a single proton or neutron inside the nucleus without producing any new matter;
- **Coulomb excitation**, in which the proton inelastically scatters off of the nucleus, exciting it to a higher energy level; and
- **Resonance production**, in which the proton inelastically scatters off of a nucleon, converting it to a higher-mass baryon.

These are arranged roughly in order of increasing momentum transfer; elastic scattering happens at low momentum transfer, and resonance production happens at higher momentum transfer.

At even higher momentum transfer (above a few proton masses), nucleon-nucleon interactions give way to interactions between quarks and/or gluons, and the collisions begin to look more like proton-proton collisions in the LHC (modified to account for all of the "spectator" nuclear matter surrounding the collision area), in which all manner of exotic matter can be produced.